# Rails ActiveRecord Query: Count, group and extra column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, count, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a model called `service` each service has one or more `usage` of a particular `song` (joined on `usage.song_id`). I want to search through the usages and find the most common songs:

```
Usage.joins(:song).group(:song_id, :song_name).count :song_id
```

I want those ordered by the count value so I add (just before `.count`)

```
.order("count_song_id DESC")
```

But now I also want the date of the most recent use of that song which is one of the details stored in the `service` model. So I know I need to add to my join:

```
Usage.joins(:song, :service)
```

So basically now I have:

```
Usage.joins(:song, :service).group(:song_id, :song_name).order("count_song_id DESC").count :song_id
```

But how do I get the *most recent* date for each song sung in the output?

**Update:** Ideally I'm looking for output something like this:

```
[
  :song_id,
  :song_name,
  count_of_this_songs_usages,
  most_recent_date_this_song_was_used
]
```

Comment: I think your phrasing is a little confusing. What's the expected output?

Comment: If I got you correct, I think you are looking for something along the lines of `Usage.joins(:song, :service).order('services.last_used_date desc').group(:song_id, :song_name).order('count_song_id desc').select('count(usages.song_id) as count, services.last_used_date as last_used_date')` You probably need to refactor the code though but the idea is there

Comment: It seems I have a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group problem

Comment: Probably much faster if u split up up lol

Comment: Ja, and I think the added complexity is that I'm trying to order by the result of a function

Comment: Yeah. Actually splitting into two queries would save the nested many to many join which is really costly. Problem solved for the time being until someone comes and provide a better answer. In fact I think having the two queries will be good enough.

Comment: Actually I haven't managed to get your code to work. I'm playing with this right now though: `Usage.select("MAX(services.date)", :song_name, "count(song_id) as count_song_id").joins(:service, :song).group(:song_name).order("count_song_id DESC")` but there seems to be something dodgy going on with it (the date is often not right, I don't think).

Comment: Oops.. I'm sorry. Haha. But yeah, I think the idea is there. Just... not sure whether selecting max is suitable actually, since there's a grouping by count_song_id. Perhaps ordering is better. Let's see when an answer comes by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm trying this. Whether two functions in the select statement are actually working correctly remains to be seen.

```
Usage.select("MAX(services.date)", :song_name, "COUNT(song_id) AS count_song_id").joins(:service, :song).group(:song_name).order("count_song_id DESC")
```